# 3D BSP tree links?

Tags: bsp-tree

The internet is filled with information on BSP trees in 2 dimensions (i.e. raycasting, all walls are parallel). Does anyone have any links or know of a book that discusses BSP trees in 3 dimensions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are not afraid in going deep into the code, you can take a look at the [Quake3 source code](ftp://ftp.idsoftware.com/idstuff/source/quake3-1.32b-source.zip) using 3D BSP. You can be sure it is well coded, at least for a real time, game oriented application.

Wikipedia should be enough if you need only high-level concepts.

Answer (score 4):

Some articles on the subject:

- Bernstein, Gilbert, and Don Fussell. "Fast, exact, linear booleans." Computer Graphics Forum. Vol. 28. No. 5. Blackwell Publishing Ltd, 2009.
- Campen, Marcel, and Leif Kobbelt. "Exact and Robust (Self‐) Intersections for Polygonal Meshes." Computer Graphics Forum. Vol. 29. No. 2. Blackwell Publishing Ltd, 2010.
- Comba, João, and Bruce Naylor. "Conversion of binary space partitioning trees to boundary representation." Geometric Modeling: Theory and Practice. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 1997. 286-301.
- Lysenko, Mikola, Roshan D’Souza, and Ching-Kuan Shene. "Improved binary space partition merging." Computer-Aided Design 40.12 (2008): 1113-1120.
- Naylor, Bruce, John Amanatides, and William Thibault. "Merging BSP trees yields polyhedral set operations." ACM Siggraph Computer Graphics 24.4 (1990): 115-124.
- Thibault, William Charles. "Application of binary space partitioning trees to geometric modeling and ray-tracing." (1987).
- Thibault, William C., and Bruce F. Naylor. "Set operations on polyhedra using binary space partitioning trees." ACM SIGGRAPH computer graphics 21.4 (1987): 153-162.
- Vaněček Jr, George. "Brep-index: a multidimensional space partitioning tree." International Journal of Computational Geometry & Applications 1.03 (1991): 243-261.
- Vanecek, George. "Incremental Construction of Multi-Dimen-sional Space Partitioning Trees." (1994).
- Wang, Charlie CL, and Dinesh Manocha. "Efficient boundary extraction of BSP solids based on clipping operations." Visualization and Computer Graphics, IEEE Transactions on 19.1 (2013): 16-29.